# Can I replace a certain character in path with another character in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have some URLs have dot-separated path like "/sub/com.domain.app" and "/sub/com.domain.app.module1", but in Nginx the the resources are located in "/sub/com/domain/app" and "/sub/com/domain/app/module1"

Is there anyway that I can rewrite all dots with slashes(/) in similar URL on that Nginx server?

Thank you very much.